# Why is assigning array entries in a loop slower?

Tags: go

I've found this weird benchmarking result that seems to say assigning the elements of an array is faster if it's not done in a loop. Hopefully someone can explain it. The full Go code is below and the benchmark `BenchmarkDirectAssignment` seems to run ten times faster even though it's doing the same thing:

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkLoopAssignment(b *testing.B) {
  arr := make([]int, 10)
  for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
      arr[i] = n
    }
  }
}

func BenchmarkDirectAssignment(b *testing.B) {
  arr := make([]int, 10)
  for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
    arr[0] = n
    arr[1] = n
    arr[2] = n
    arr[3] = n
    arr[4] = n
    arr[5] = n
    arr[6] = n
    arr[7] = n
    arr[8] = n
    arr[9] = n
  }
}
```

```
$ go test -bench=.
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkLoopAssignment-16              500000000                3.76 ns/op
BenchmarkDirectAssignment-16            2000000000               0.25 ns/op
PASS
ok      _/D_/go_benchmark       3.107s
```

I've replicated this in Java and C# and got the same result - the direct assignment is always faster. Does anyone know why this would happen? Thanks!

Comment: Your first example has all the overhead of actually doing the loop - all of the instructions in the `for` part, incrementing and testing `i`, jumping around, etc. When compared to just assigning an array element, that's significant.

Comment: There's a big difference, the first you have nested loops, the second you have one. The test cases are different, so your finding's are inconclusive as well.

Comment: Congratulations - you have discovered [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)! Note that the .Net JIT compiler [can do loop unrolling for some cases](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/844781/Digging-Into-NET-Loop-Performance-Bounds-checking) (for release builds).

Comment: I ran some tests in Java using JMH. [code](https://pastebin.com/3Dwj1H5D) [results](https://pastebin.com/SE3c7eQz). Conclusion: Unrolling it by hand is slightly slower. Also, the value of `b.N` doesn't matter, will be optimized away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 1st example, you have a loop. Each itteration will be at least 1 jump + modifiying and checking the running variable. That is your overhead on top of the assignment.

In the 2nd example, you hardcoded the assignments. Those orders can jsut be read sequentially. No jump, counting or checking related overheads.

However it is worth pointing out, that the difference hardly ever maters:

https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

It is not like you could use case 2 for really large lists anyway. At least not this side of some automated code creation,

Answer (score 0):

The first example involves few additional computation that uses cpu, memory before real assignation is going to be done. 
But for the second example it is a direct assignment without more computation.
As other answer mentioned it doesn't really matter for this example cases , but for more complex/large data set , it really important how algorithm should work efficiently.

The above result might be same for other programming languages as well since the computation is same.

Some good notes on complexity and big-O , this might be helpful 
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html